# Lufthansa economy light personal item?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, lufthansa

I just bought a trip travelling to the US with Lufthansa's economy light fare. I have previously travelled with Lufthansa and I have been allowed to take a ''personal item'' AND a carry on, however, this time around I can't find any info about a personal item and just about the carry-on! so do I dare bring two bags or will I be charged extra?

Answer (score 5):

With Lufthansa you can always bring a carry on and a personal item, as mentioned on the page https://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/carry-on-baggage. The problem is, that the part about the personal item on that page is not translated to english. It's the part under "Zusätzliche kostenfreie Gepäckstücke in der Kabine", which says

> Ein weiteres kleines Gepäckstück (max. x=30 cm y=40 cm z=10 cm, z. B. Handtasche, Laptoptasche).

Translated by me:

> Additional free items in the cabin: One further small luggage item, max 40x30x10 cm, e.g. purse, laptop bag etc.